# for loop with async closure

Tags: swift, for-loop, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to pass some array through segue but before that I have to run simple for loop but I have a problem. For each iteration I need so perform a function with networking and async. After complete, it has to append String to array and after for loop ends, pass the data on segue.

I have a problem because when try this, I get crash for data not being passed and is nil on new controller. I am assuming, I need to use GCD or something similar to inform when all is complete and that pass data.

What I tried first:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

selectedStory = stories[indexPath.row]

for chapter in (selectedStory?.chapters)! {
  DataService.instance.retrieveUsername(forID: chapter.author) { (returnedUsernamed) in
    self.selectedStoryChapterAuthors?.append(returnedUsernamed)

  }
}

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToStory", sender: self)}
```

How I tried to make this work with DispatchGroup but didn't work:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

selectedStory = stories[indexPath.row]

for chapter in (selectedStory?.chapters)! {
  dispatchGroup.enter()  //  Enter the dispatch group
  DataService.instance.retrieveUsername(forID: chapter.author) { (returnedUsernamed) in
    self.selectedStoryChapterAuthors?.append(returnedUsernamed)

    self.dispatchGroup.leave()
  }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToStory", sender: self)
}) }
```

Any idea on this? If more info/code needed, lemme know.

Comment: What is the point to _wait_ an async call in order to perform your segue?... Wouldn't be better to perform your segue, and _then_ make the calls to fetch any data that is needed asynchronously?

Comment: How would I do that, if I am relying on this data that needs to be passed on other controller I am going to? I have tableview there and as soon as its loaded, tableview should get number of rows based on this data array count and cell data from that as well.

Comment: A common approach for this is to show a loading view/indicator while fetching the data, and reload your tableview when you have finished.

Comment: What does "but didn't work" mean?

Comment: matt it means that when I came through segue app crashed because there was no data being passed from first VC

Comment: @Alladinian so CellForRow method is only called when I reload data? Because if I set to display data on cell from something that is still to fetch, I get crash. How would I configure cell (set text label to string from data) that is still to fetch upon controller load?

Comment: `cellForRow` is called multiple times, but it's in your hand to return zero number of rows until you got some data to display...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution with some help.
I basically ran for loop in second view controller and main thing that made it work was to add

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  // cell configuration
}
```

in CellForRow method.

Thanks for inputs!